# Best place to include javascript in a field formatter?

Tags: 7, javascript, entities

I've created a custom field formatter using [hook_field_formatter_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7) and implemented it using [hook_field_formatter_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_view/7).

My formatter requires additional javascript though and at the moment I'm including it in hook_field_formatter_view() but I have a feeling there's gotta be a better place to do this.

However there is no hook_field_formatter_preprocess() (there is a formatter_prepare_view() though but it doesnt't seem right)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the JavaScript in hook_field_formatter_view() works just fine. Just also be sure to use #attached and not drupal_add_js() since that way your file is included in the render cache.

```
function mymodule_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $element = array();
  $settings = $display['settings'];

  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    $element[$delta] = // Blah blah blah add output for each $items in $element as a render array.
  }

  // Add the JavaScript file.
  $element['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.field.js;

  return $element;
}
```

Comment: Since I was calling a theme function in the formatter_view() anyway I just moved the include js part to hook_preprocess_hook(), this is great know to know though!

Comment: can we add css also in the same way?  `$element['#attached']['css'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/mymodule.field.css;`